# How do you set up an x64 development environment based on gcc and eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, windows-7, ide, 64-bit

I want to create 64 bit apps for (for example) 64 bit Windows 7. I've searched the web and found some help but couldn't get it to work.

---

Sorry I've taken so long to respond but I have tried to get the packages suggested to work but they're not easy or else I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway I ran across an environment called pellesc. It consists of a development environment around a compiler which traces is roots back to a 32-bit version that was once (according to Wikipedia) used to develop Quake. From what I've seen so far it's very promising and generates good code too!

Comment: These days I recommend TDM's gcc for x86-64 with Eclipse for C. New gcc versions are converted and released shortly after they arrive on gnu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Eclipse MinGW64 tutorial](http://pinyotae.blogspot.com/2010/05/eclipse-mingw-x64.html) mentions:

> update (Nov 9, 2010): recent **[MinGW-w64 versions](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)** come with '`as`', '`g++`', and '`gcc`' commands.  This step may be unnecessary in your MinGW build.

Meaning you won't have anymore to update the GCC assembler, C++ compiler, C compiler and C++ linker, with '`x86_64-w64-mingw32-as`', '`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`', '`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`', and '`x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`'.

Other great source for w64 development tools:

[Native windows x64 software develop with Mingw-w64 on drangon.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623233023/www.drangon.org/mingw)

Answer (score 1):

In spite of what other people are saying, Eclipse actually has very good support for C++, even in Windows: check out the [CDT project](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/). It's very mature and well-supported -- it works for C/C++ at least as well as Eclipse JDT works for Java.

As for the compiler itself, VonC is right, [MinGW-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) (but the mingw-w64 project is moving to mingw-w64.org so i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org)) is the best option. Eclipse CDT has built-in support for MinGW so as long as you install MinGW first, Eclipse should automatically detect it.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit version of GCC for Windows is available at http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download. I can't see why you would want to use Eclipse for C or C++ programming - try the Code::Blocks IDE at http://www.codeblocks.org instead.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Its compatable with unix so you can easily move systems and has tons of functionality that is gcc friendly (autoconf, make, makedepends, ...). To use gcc to compile to 64 bit add the -m64 option. To compile for windows use the -mno-cygwin option. Make sure though that you're using gcc 3 and not 4 (then you'd use the mingw compiler series). Otherwise, its all the same as unix which is really useful.

Comment: `-mno-cygwin` has been deprecated for a while now.  Use MinGW instead.

Comment: its still there in gcc 3 though and I find it easier to use. I did mention mingw though.